# Unpermitted Parameter: referred_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, cookies, devise

I am making a referral system that stores the referral part of the url in a cookie with this code.

```
before_filter :capture_referral

private
def capture_referral
  session[:ref] = params[:ref] if params[:ref]
end
```

I then call that `session[:ref]` in my Devise User Register html.erb like so `<%= f.hidden_field :referred_by, value: session[:ref]%>` and I know the cookie is working because the output of the params are:

```
Aunticity_token"=>"CmYKwW8LxRAIz1eLp6tQcwJefvnEMU1xV3aby0/pWKGqyd4WitO8oTcDu0u+51HcGB7eyyXZzn2jbEg+D48d4A==",  
  "user"=>{
    "email"=>"jexuc@gmail.com", 
    "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
    "referred_by"=>"jayhaz"}, 
  "commit"=>"Sign up"}`
```

However, in the output there is a `Unpermitted parameter: referred_by` which stops the referred_by code being saved to the User's database entry.

I also tried the following and it still didn't work, and yes it is declared in my `routes.rb` file:

```
class User::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys:[:referred_by])
   # devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys:[:first_name, :last_user])
  end
end
```

Absolutely no clue what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, I had to put

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email,:password,:password_confirmation,:referred_by])
# devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys:[:first_name, :last_user])
end
```

In my `application_controller.rb` and not my `User::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`. I am not entirely sure why it works but I think it might have to do with `application_controller` carrying through the entire app and not just sitting at the `Devise::RegistrationsController` level. Could be wrong let me know in the comments.